# MVC - How to use Count inside a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to display amount comments a user have wrote total by Count inside a View.

How do I do that?

```
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">      

        <dt>
           User:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            Total reviews: 
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @*Count total comments in db*@
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

This is how the model looks like for `CommentReview`. `UserId` gets it fk-value from `User` table.

```
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ReviewId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
```

Comment: What are you passing to the view ? A collection of CommentToReview objects ? Why not use the `Count` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view should not know about any database related things (think about it as the view only does what it is good at: displaying stuff).

Thus, you might want to move that code out into another place, where it could safely retrieve the information. You can do this in your controller if you really want to (for something small), which is better than the view.

Remember to add the property to your model.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will try solve it from controller.  What do you mean by add the property to my model? The count you mean?

Comment: Remember that in MVC you need to pass the model to your view. The model should include the any data that you will need for your view. So you need a property on there called something like 'countOfItems' or something to draw it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Either change your view model to include list of comments and in the view use `@Model.Count`, or keep the model as is and retrive the count of the user comments in hte controller action and set a ViewBag property with the total comments count, ex: `ViewBag.CommentsCount = /* gt it from DB*/`

Then in your view, output it using `@ViewBag.CommentsCount`